# How to turn this .htaccess rule into a dynamic rule with add_rewrite_rule, et al?

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

In .htaccess, I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^land/(.*) /?land=1&exper=$1 [QSA,L]
```

which makes sth like this: domain.com/land/exper1
fill in the $_GET with

$_GET['land'] = 1 and $_GET['exper'] = exper1

Great.

I want to take this out of .htaccess and add the rule dynamically, that is, look for other querystring values like 'ocean' instead of 'land'.  I want the values to be filled into $_GET or some other var where I can evaluate them.  I cant figure out if add_rewrite_rule is sposed to actually overwrite my .htaccess, but all the things i've tried, flush_rewrite_rules(true), etc arent doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and follow the same structure to add more rewrite rules or query vars:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars');
function my_query_vars( $vars) {
    $vars[] = "land";
    $vars[] = "expert";
   return $vars;
}

// Add the new rewrite rule to existings ones
add_action('init','my_rewrite_rules');
function my_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'land/(.+)/?$' , 'index.php?land=1&expert=$matches[1]' , 'top' );
}
```

Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules by going to the admin area->Settings->permalinks->click save.

Comment: And then I can access those vars with $wp_query->query_vars['land'] 
Thanks!

Comment: @DougCassidy $wp_query->get('land') do the same and you write less ;)